# org.jasypt.spring31.properties.EncryptablePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer:Even though dependency added to Spring framework

Tags: java, spring, maven, encryption

I'm new to spring-maven framework.i'm encrypting my database password present in properties file using jasypt encryption.In my applicationConntext file i'm using **org.jasypt.spring31.properties.EncryptablePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer**  package to read encrypted password as well as to decrypt it.I used **asypt-spring31** dependency in POM.xml,after adding this dependency its giving missing arifact-id.I checked in my maven repository spring31-jar is not generated.If i use the spring31-jar of my project works correctly.But i have to use dependency to achieve my task.Please help me out to resolve this issue.

Comment: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jasypt/jasypt-spring31

Comment: I added that dependency to POM.xml of my project.

Comment: Can you provide the exact error? I included the dependency in my maven project, it works fine.